# How to fix "_init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'" error when using Updater class of python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've been working on a Telegram bot using python for a while and everything was fine, but today I was starting to work on a new project but I got a lot of errors. So, I uninstalled it and installed it again and I tried a simple code like this below:

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext, ConversationHandler
from telegram import KeyboardButton

def main():
       
    updater = Updater(token="5934903868:AAGckQGHTbYwpAwdqGh9o5Zs2Hfdcb1PyZs")
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', startCommand))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but I keep getting this error:

> *init*_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'

Comment: [`Updater`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/54d0294f92539fa1d0954ed4185b061bd12341d2/telegram/ext/_updater.py#L100) has only `bot` and `update_queue` arguments

Comment: You should revoke the token that you posted. Talk to botfather to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are currently utilizing version `<=13.15` of the `python-telegram-bot` library. It's worth noting that this library has undergone significant changes in version 20.0. To ensure compatibility and access to new features, it's recommended to upgrade to version 20.0 by reviewing the [release notes](https://telegra.ph/Release-notes-for-python-telegram-bot-v200a0-05-06) and the [transition guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0).
If you wish to continue using your existing code, you can install version 13.15 via `pip install python-telegram-bot==13.15`. However, please be aware that this version is outdated and will no longer receive official support or bug fixes in the future. If you're starting a new project, it is suggested to use version 20.0.

Comment: Yadva I checked the new documentation and did the changes.. but i got a new error saying **Cannot close a running event loop**

Comment: Im using jupyter notebook by the way

Comment: @johnx Please come to the official telegram chat of this library so we can help you better. here's the link: https://telegram.me/pythontelegrambotgroup

Answer (score 2):

Updater's constructor method doesn't accept that specific keyword argument. From the [docs](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html#telegram-ext-updater), it looks like Updater's constructor accepts an argument bot, an instance of [Bot](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram-bot), an object that can be initialized with token.

Try this

```
from telegram import Bot

myBot = Bot('your token')
updater = Updater(myBot)
```

Comment: Its `telegram.Bot` directly (there is no .ext involved here).