# Error with updater Telegram Bot with python-telegram-bot v20.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

How can I fix this error I get with when I start telegram bot with v20 version of python-telegram-bot ?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/bot3/botig.py", line 104, in <module>
main()
File "/home/pi/Desktop/bot3/botig.py", line 95, in main
updater = Updater("MY-BOT-TOKEN")
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'
```

the code is:

```py
def main():
    # Crea il database se non esiste
    conn = sqlite3.connect('instagram_links.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS links (
                    user_id INTEGER,
                    link TEXT,
                    time TIMESTAMP
                )""")
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS banned_users (
                    user_id INTEGER
                )""")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    # Inserisci gli ID delle persone autorizzate a utilizzare il comando /ban
    authorized_users = [557477429,87654321]

    # Crea l'updater e gli handler per i comandi
    updater = Updater("Token", use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("add", add_link))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("ban", ban_user))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

It gives me that error that I can't fix

Comment: You left your Bot token in your traceback. You should revoke it ASAP!

Comment: does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75187329/16632834