# Good afternoon. I am writing the simplest bot for Telegrams. Can you tell me what the problem is?

Tags: python

Good afternoon, I'm writing the simplest bot for Telegram, an error occurs at the moment of launching the bot, tell me where I'm wrong or maybe the code is outdated?

> Error:
> updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
> TypeError: Updater.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'

My code:

```
import telegram
    import datetime
    import time
    import logging
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext
    
    # Configure logging for the bot
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                     level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
    # Set the bot token for authentication
    TOKEN = 'BOT-TOKEN'
    
    # Create an instance of the telegram bot using the bot token
    bot = telegram.Bot(TOKEN)

    # Define a function to handle the 'setreminder' command from the user
    def set_reminder(update, context):
        chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
        text = update.message.text
        try:
            task, time_str = text.split(' ', 1)
            time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            if time_obj <= now:
                update.message.reply_text('Время напоминания должно быть больше текущего времени!')
                return
            delta = time_obj - now
            seconds = delta.seconds + delta.days * 24 * 3600
            context.job_queue.run_once(send_reminder, seconds, context={'chat_id': chat_id, 'task':         task})
            update.message.reply_text('Напоминание установлено!')
        except Exception as e:
            update.message.reply_text('Произошла ошибка: {}'.format(str(e)))

    # Define a function to send the reminder message to the user
    def send_reminder(context: CallbackContext):
        job = context.job
        chat_id = job.context['chat_id']
        task = job.context['task']
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f'Напоминание: {task}')

    # Define a function to handle errors that occur during the bot's operation
    def error(update, context):
        logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)
    
    # Start the bot
    #Interested in the moment
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
        dp = updater.dispatcher

        dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("setreminder", set_reminder))
        dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, set_reminder))
        dp.add_error_handler(error)

        updater.start_polling()
        updater.idle()
```

Comment: What version of the library are you using? Check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75183847/i-keep-getting-token-error-on-python-telegram-bot

Comment: ver. python-telegram-bot 20.2

Comment: The error is telling you that Updater doesn’t expect a token argument.