# How to fix "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token', updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)"

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, filters

# Define your Telegram bot token
TOKEN = '6zgnMSjLQ'

# Define the keyword you want to track
KEYWORD = 'June' , 'July', 'Auguest'

# Define the function to handle incoming messages
def handle_message(update, context):
    message = update.message
    if message.text and KEYWORD.lower() in message.text.lower():
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                                 text=f"Keyword '{KEYWORD}' mentioned: {message.text}")

# Set up the bot
def main():
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Register the message handler
    message_handler = MessageHandler(filters.text, handle_message)
    dispatcher.add_handler(message_handler)

    # Start polling for new messages
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am trying to make the bot scrape a continous group and notify me whenever the keyword has mentioned and I am having these errors. I make the bot using Botfather and received the token.

Comment: Seems the `Updater` class (as of v20.3) does not anymore accept a `token` parameter. https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html#updater. Also see their docs on changes with v20 specifically for `Updater`: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0#updater "*It now only accepts the arguments bot and update_queue and only has those attributes.*" Either use an older version of the library or adapt your code for the newer version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I keep getting Token error on python-telegram-bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75183847/i-keep-getting-token-error-on-python-telegram-bot)

Comment: Hey. You seem to be using a version >=20.0 of python-telegram-bot  but your code is written for version <=13.15. Please either upgrade your code to  v20 by reading the [release notes](https://telegra.ph/Release-notes-for-python-telegram-bot-v200a0-05-06) and the [transition guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0) or install a version of PTB that is compatible with your code base. Also note that only v20 is officially supported and the library has undergone significant changes