# Python-telegram-bot using-context version error

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I searched about it , and i asked from AI and i noticed the problem is because of the new version after python-telegram-bot 12 library.

So some of them say , just simply remove the using-context but i did it and i don't know what is wrong. This is the code. I learned it from a video on YouTube that probably was a little old.

```
import constants as keys
from telegram.ext import *
import responses as R


print('Bot starting ... ')
def start_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply('type something random so')

def help_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply('this is my help command.')



def handle_message(update, context):
    text = str(update.message.text).lower() 
    Response = R.sample_responses(text) 

    update.message.reply_text(response)

def error(update, context):
    print(f'Update {update} caused error {context.error}')

# most important function    most important function 
def main():
    ##### this line is my error 
    updater = Updater(keys.API_KEY)
# before removing using-context:
# updater = Updater(keys.API_KEY, using-context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))


    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))

    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

print("polling ... ")
main()
```

So the error with using-context:

```
File "/storage/emulated/0/1_code/someall/telegram/python/1/main.py", line 27
    updater = Updater(keys.API_KEY, using-context=True)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

So this is error when i removed the using-context :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/1_code/someall/telegram/python/1/main.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "/storage/emulated/0/1_code/someall/telegram/python/1/main.py", line 27, in main
    updater = Updater(keys.API_KEY)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "\_init\_\_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'" error when using Updater class of python-telegram-bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75183847/how-to-fix-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-token-error-when-usi)

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of "using-context=True"
use this

```
use_context=True
```